# When using the same Vertex shader in different programs, does the uniform location persist

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader

sorry if this is a duplicate I can't seem to find a solid answer.

If i use the same vertex shader in multiple programs is it safe to assume the getUniformLocation will stay the same?

example, if i use the following vertex shader in multiple programs (A,B,C,D):

```
uniform mat4    uMvp;
attribute vec3 aPosition;

void main() {
             vec4 position = vec4(aPosition.xyz, 1.);
             gl_Position = uMvp * position;
 }
```

and at initialization I was to call

```
 GLUint mvpLoc = getUniformLocation("uMvp");
```

while using program A, would i safely be able to switch to program B/C/D and carry on using mvploc? I am relatively new to GLES 2.0 and on the face of it this seems like bad practice but I assume there is overhead when calling getUniformLocation that would be good to avoid.

I have read about glBindAttribLocation so i could use that and instead have uMvp as a attribute but then I feel like i am missing a point as the common practice seems to be mvps as uniform variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, each program program object will have separate uniform locations. There's no way to guarantee that two different programs use the same location for the same uniform.

Unless you have access to ARB_explicit_uniform_locations or GL 4.3 (which you don't, since you're using ES). This allows you to explicitly specify uniform locations in the shader.

Comment: "There's no way to guarantee that two different programs use the same location for the same uniform." It is just they are completely separate objects with different internal state. You need to specify uniforms for both as you stated :)

Comment: This is what i thought, but then what is the argument for not just using glBindAttribLocation most of the time, it seems far more helpful to use this for most situation e.g. the model view matrix

Comment: @chrispepper1989: Attributes change per-vertex. You could use 4 per-vertex attributes for a 4x4 matrix, using `glVertexAttrib`. But the performance characteristics of this will be unknown (since most people don't do that). Also, you only generally get 16 attributes *total*, you will strictly limit the number of "uniforms" you can use.

Comment: I assume then its good practice to set up some form of ShaderObject class, that would hold each uniform variable location

Comment: no, native tizen. the "shader object" class approach seems to be relatively popular (judging by some examples I have come across) so i will probably stick to that, especially after Nicol Bolas's comment